# Using Django Templates, how can I access values from my model in the JavaScript header?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Using Django, I can successfully read and display values from my model in the content segment of my template, but I can't get the values from my model in the head segment of my template.

Here's the code -->

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from host.models import Event

def EventSingle(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('event.html', {'eventobject': Event.objects.get(slug=slug)})
```

event.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var variable1;
        variable1="click worked";
        //variable1={{ eventobject.datetime }};

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#pic").click(function (b) {
                alert(variable1);
            });
        });
    </script>   
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="eventobject">

        <p>{{ eventobject }}</p>
        <p>{{ eventobject.location }}</p>
        <p>{{ eventobject.datetime }}</p>

        <img id="pic" src="{{ eventobject.image1.url }}" />

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

When clicking on the image, an alert box pops up with the text "click worked", but if I comment out `variable1="click worked";` and un-comment `variable1={{ eventobject.datetime }};` nothing happens when I click on the image. Can I not use model references in the head section of django template? All other references to the model in the content block display the values from the DB properly.

Comment: have you tried: variable1="{{ eventobject.datetime }}";

Answer (score 1):

I guess `eventobject.datetime` must be a string or python datetime object.

If it is a string, change your code to :

```
variable1= "{{ eventobject.datetime }}" ;
```

If it is a datetime object, use django template filter :

```
variable1= "{{ eventobject.datetime|date:"D d M Y" }}"
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

If you do not put the quotes, the javascript statement looks like:

```
variable1 = 2013-05-30 ;
```

which is INCORRECT javascript syntax, the quotes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date), you can use a date filter to format date:

```
variable1= '{{ eventobject.datetime|date:"d-m-Y" }}';
```

Additionally, you can also set [DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#date-format) (or DATETIME_FORMAT) setting to set a project-wide default for displaying such values.